# PHP is selecting the same row 3 times?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP to select all results from a user_uploads table based on who it is uploaded by.

Here is my PHP:

```
require_once("class.user.php");
$auth_user = new USER();

$user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];

$stmt_user_uploads = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM user_uploads WHERE uploaded_by = :user_name");
$stmt_user_uploads->execute(array(":user_name"=>$_GET['username']));
$user_uploads = $stmt_user_uploads->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

There are 6 rows in the user_uploads table all from the same user, so in theory I should have 6 different results, however; 3 of the same are repeated? Below is my foreach loop.

```
<?php
    if($user_uploads['uploaded_by'] == true) {
        foreach ($user_uploads as $row) {
            echo '<div class="style col-md-3">';
                echo '<div class="hovereffect">';
                    echo '<img src="'. $user_uploads['file_name'] .'" alt="" class="img-responsive" />';
                echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }

    else {
        echo '<p>This user has not uploaded any images.</p>';
    }
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could those three be duplicated in the database as well?

Comment: There are 6 different rows, I manually added them in to the database, they are not the same. :)

Comment: Ok just checking =)

Answer (score 2):

You're using your loop variables wrong:

```
$user_uploads = $stmt_user_uploads->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   ^---one single ROW of results from the query, as an array

        foreach ($user_uploads as $row) {
                     ^---your single row result array
                                   ^---one FIELD of data from your row

                    echo '<img src="'. $user_uploads['file_name'] .'" alt="" class="img-responsive" />';
                                            ^---ignoring the field you fetched
```

Since your `echo` uses `$user_uploads`, you're always using the **SAME** field to output a value, completely ignoring the `$row` which would contain a different value each time the loop iterates.

As well, since `fetch()` only returns ONE row of data from your possible 6 rows, you completely ignore the other 5 records.

You need to do

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
     echo $row['user_name'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Marc B, I am an idiot... I'll mark this as an answer in 7 minutes!

Answer (score 0):

It is normal to process multiple rows from a result set in some kind of loop like this, getting each row in turn and doing whatever is required with it inside the loop

```
require_once("class.user.php");
$auth_user = new USER();

$user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];

$stmt_user_uploads = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM user_uploads WHERE uploaded_by = :user_name");
$stmt_user_uploads->execute(array(":user_name"=>$_GET['username']));
while ( $row = $stmt_user_uploads->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    echo '<div class="style col-md-3">';
        echo '<div class="hovereffect">';
            echo '<img src="'. $row['file_name'] .'" alt="" class="img-responsive" />';
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

This way you will process all the rows and not just the first as in your example